# Skipping input stream values

Tags: c++, istream

Is there any easy mechanism to skip until the next whitespace with a C++ input stream (like `ifstream`)?

I know that I can use `ignore` if I know how many characters to skip or what delimiter to expect. But IMO it's ugly to use `ignore` when `operator>>` usually just reads to the next whitespace without supplying any additional parameters. I could also use a dummy, but that only makes matters worse.

#### Example

```
auto importantInfo1 = 0;
auto importantInfo2 = 0;
auto someDummy = 0; // This is ugly and doesn't clearly express the intent

file >> importantInfo1 >> someDummy >> importantInfo2;
```

Also in some cases I will need more than one dummy if I need to handle different datatypes in the "skip"-case.

I would imagine something like this:

```
file >> importantInfo1;
file.skip<int>(1);
file >> importantInfo2;
```

Or maybe even better:

```
auto importantInfo1 = 0;
auto importantInfo2 = 0;

file >> importantInfo1 >> skip<int> >> importantInfo2;
```

I imagine such a solution would also perform better than actually parsing and storing the value somewhere when it is never needed.

### Possible solution

Made this solution using the answers provided. It's basically the same as the accepted answer, but it doesn't need a temporary. Instead, it skips the first whitespaces, then skips any character except whitespaces until whitespace is reached again. This solution may use 2 while loops but doesn't need to know about the extracted type. I'm not saying this is a high performance solution or anything fancy, but it makes the resulting code shorter, cleaner and more expressive.

```
template<typename CharT, typename Traits>
inline std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& skip(std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>& stream)
{
    while (stream && std::isspace(stream.peek())) stream.ignore();
    while (stream && !std::isspace(stream.peek())) stream.ignore();
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: I might be wrong,  but it looks like you're not skipping white space; you're scanning for integers.

Comment: Did you try to implement a skip<T> template? sounds like a reasonable idea

Comment: You have to parse the value (storing an int is inexpensive)

Comment: @Proxy Technically I am scanning for integers, but it's not only integers, this was just an example. The point is that I'm not interested in the result.

Comment: @MatthiasBonora I would, but I don't really know where to start. But I will try to come up with something.

Comment: @DieterLücking The performance part would be an added bonus, I know it's not that much of a performance hit. Maybe the `int` was a bad example, it could be a string, or some complex object which provides a stream operator.

Comment: Does [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) work?

Comment: `std::cin >> std::ws` skips all whitespace.

Comment: @Proxy This whole question is more about clean C++ code, using `scanf` is no real option.

Comment: @Simple I don't want to skip whitespaces, I want to skip any value in the stream until I reach the next whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea having a manipulator to skip data is the right way to go.

Skip 'trivial' data:

```
#include <sstream>

template<typename T, typename Char, typename Traits>
inline std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>& skip(std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>& stream) {
    T unused;
    return stream >> unused;
}

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in("1 666 2 ");
    int a;
    int b;
    in >> a >> skip<int> >> b;
    std::cout << a << b << '\n';
}
```

If the data gets more complex and construction/streaming becomes expensive you have to provide an specialized overload and parse char by char to skip it.

Comment: Works like a charm and will suffice for primitive datatypes. Thank you! Maybe I will rewrite the skip-function to use `ignore` or `readline` to directly skip to the next WS without even needing the temporary.

Answer (score 1):

write Your own ignore

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

template< typename E, typename Traits, typename Pred >
std::basic_istream< E, Traits >& ignore_until( std::basic_istream< E, Traits >& in, Pred end )
{
    std::basic_istream< E, Traits >::sentry ok( in );
    if( ok )
    {
        std::ios_base::iostate state = std::ios_base::goodbit;
        try
        {
            for( Traits::int_type m = in.rdbuf()->sgetc(); ; m = in.rdbuf()->snextc() )
            {
                if( Traits::eq_int_type( m, Traits::eof() ) )
                {
                    state |= std::ios_base::eofbit;
                    break;
                }
                const E c = Traits::to_char_type( m );
                if( end( c ) )
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            state |= std::ios_base::badbit;
            if( in.exceptions() & std::ios_base::badbit )
                throw;
        }
        in.setstate( state );
    }
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    locale loc = cin.getloc();
    for( int i; ignore_until( cin, [&loc]( char c ) { return std::isspace(c,loc); } ) >> i; )
        cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but it's just too much code for such a simple purpose. Also, I don't really gain much by calling `ignore_until` and providing `isspace` by myself (although I could integrate that check in `ignore_until` easily ofc). I'm not scared of using `ignore` and the likes, I just want a shorter and more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted something like the skip in the last example then you could create a class Skip that overloads operator>>. You would need something like:

```
class Skip {
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, Skip &skip);
};

istream& operator>> (istream &in, Skip &skip) {
    // I'm not sure why you are parameterizing skip, but this is where
    // you would do whatever handles that
}
```

Comment: Yeah the template parameter might not be necessary. I was just thinking that some streaming implementations for more complex datatypes might need some special treatment.